# Authentication in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Current project uses Spring boot , Thymeleaf and Jquery for web application . We want to add angular to this project for specific module using ng-view and route provider.

Currently Login/other modules are in jquery and thymeleaf.

Please advise on below questions - stuck unable to find solution.

1.How to verify if the user is authenticated when user navigates in this view or in routes?
2.How to get roles associated to this user inside controllers or services?
3.How to load login page after user is logged out by server ?

Comment: if you can do it with jquery you can do it with angularjs, why is your authentication different in angularjs? you have to authenticate trough a web service using tokens and from there you can get roles and authorize based on that. _how to get roles? what are you using in your server side?, roles are married to the token itself_ a login page in AngularJS is a single view, Angular is a **SPA Framework** how is the user logged off by the server?

Comment: currently authentication is done by submitting username/password to spring boot and thymeleaf server side processing is used to show pages Sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN') based on roles. Once the user is logged in when user clicks on angular module how to ensure user is authenticated and if it fails load back login page.If the user is logged in then perform routing and get roles of the user.